# Trying to skip test case based on condition in a loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

I have the following test code, my intention is when looping thru objects I want to check the condition and run for first time and assign `go_on` value to `false` and skip tests when false. I tested this code without looping thru the object and it works. I use nodejs and mocha test framework.

```
var s={a:c,b:a};

Object.keys(s).forEach(function (x){
  before(function( done1 ){
    if (go_on==true) {        
      done1();
    }
    else this.skip();
  });
  it('Exit if go_on false', function (done) {

    go_on=false;
    console.log(go_on);

    done();
  });
});
```

Comment: It's a bit unclear what the actual question is (since there's literally no question sentence anywhere in the original post).

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are setting `go_on=false` in your `it`, but then using it in your `before`.  `before` code occurs before `it` code, so the value of `go_on` set in the `it` will never get used.

Also, you're not actually using `s` or `x` anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to skip some tests based on data conditions. You have the basic idea correct, but you need to use `beforeEach()` versus `before()`. The `before()` callback executes before the entire test suite whereas the `beforeEach()` callback runs before EACH test. Here is an example that works:

```
describe('conditional tests', function() {
  var go_on = true;
  var s={ a:'1', b:'2', c:'3'};

  Object.keys(s).forEach(function (x){
    beforeEach(function( done ){
      if (go_on === true) {
        done();
      }
      else this.skip();
    });
    it('test for ' + x, function (done) {
      if (x === 'b') {
        go_on=false;
        console.log('stopping tests');
      }
      done();
    });
  });
});
```

The resulting output is:

```
$ mocha test.js

  conditional tests
    ✓ test for a
stopping tests
    ✓ test for b
    - test for c


  2 passing (13ms)
  1 pending
```